# Poisson random variable- variance

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, poisson-distribution

Let us model the number of winter storms in a given year as a Poisson random variable. Suppose that in a good year the average number of storms is 3, and in a bad year the average is 5. If the next year will be good with probability 40% and bad with probability 60%, find the expected number of winter storms next year.

E[X] = 5*.6 + 3*.4 = 4.2 <-- correct answer

Next, find the variance of the number of winter storms next year.

I know that Var[X] = E[X^2] - E[X}^2 so when I calculated this I got:
E[X^2] = 5^2(.6) + 3^2(.4) = 18.6 and E[X]^2 = 4.2^2 = 17.64 so Var[X] = 18.6 -17.64 = .96.

However, this is not the correct answer. Any ideas of where I am going wrong?

Comment: Looks to me like your calculation of $E[X^2]$ is not right (hint: it should be up near 23). You should also *explicitly define* $X$, to help save confusion. I'd probably have used the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)

Comment: That's where I thought I was going astray, I am confused how to calculate that with what you have given me. Can you please explain further?

Comment: I am confused how you got a number up near 23. Can you please explain your inputs?

Comment: You need to know about the _total variance formula_ $$\operatorname{var}(X) = E\left[\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y)\right] + \operatorname{var}\left(E[X\mid Y]\right)$$ where $Y$ in this case is a random variable taking on values $3$ and $5$ with probabilities $0.4$ and $0.6$ respectively, and the _conditional_ distribution of $X$ given $Y = \alpha$ is Poisson with parameter $\alpha$, $\alpha = 3, 5$.

Comment: You plug into the formula for the law of total variance (see Dilip's comment for what the variables should be). It's possible to do it your way if you compute $E(X^2)$ properly, but to my mind it's actually (slightly) harder to do that [crucially you would need to start with the expected squares of the two components, not the squared expectations].

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify what you did wrong. (1) undefined variables and (2) calculating squared expectation incorrectly

If we proceed as you did, but set up the variables and notation first, we go something like this:

Let $B$ be $0$ in a good year and $1$ in a bad year. 
($B\sim\text{Bernoulli}(0.6)$)

Let $X$ be the number of storms next year.

Let $S_0$ be the number of storms in a good year. Let $S_1$ be the number of storms in a bad year.

$S_0=(X|B=0)\sim\text{Pois}(3)$

$S_1=(X|B=1)\sim\text{Pois}(5)$

Then

$$E(X) \,\,= E(S_0)\times (1-p_B)+E(S_1)\times p_B$$

$$\quad = E(S_0)\times 0.4+E(S_1)\times 0.6$$

as you calculated before (this is just the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation))

$$E(X^2) \, = E(S_0^2)\times (1-p_B)
+E(S_1^2)\times p_B$$

$$\quad = E(S_0^2)\times 0.4+E(S_1^2)\times 0.6$$

(this is the *same* formula you used for expectation, but now in terms of random variables that are the squares of the ones you had before)

Lack of notation aside, you actually are okay up to here.

The mistake is that you (implicitly) then used the variances in place of $E(S_i^2)$, which is too small. You need to add another term!

I think the problem was your lack of defined variables obscured your mistake, making it impossible for you to find.

If you do that bit right, you'll get an $E(X^2)$ which is between 22 and 23 (and is getting up toward 23 as I mentioned before).

That approach works. But to my mind the law of total variance is easier. If you've never encountered it, do the $E(X^2)$ approach - carefully.

Comment: You might want to suggest to the OP that finding $E[X^2]$ by _first_ finding $E[X(X-1)]$ _directly_ and then using $$E[X(X-1)] = E[X^2] - E[X]\quad\Rightarrow\quad E[X^2] = E[X(X-1)]+E[X]$$ is even easier than finding $E[X^2]$ _directly_ as in $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^2 p_X(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @Dilip - the factorial moments are great shortcuts for distributions like the Poisson and binomial. But I was assuming the OP would already know (and be expected to be able to use) the mean and variance of a Poisson and just compute $E(S_i^2)$ from those. Or do you mean to apply it to the $X$ as defined in my answer?

Comment: In over 35 years of teaching this stuff, I never failed to be amazed at how many students knew and could compute variances using $$\operatorname{var}(X) = E[X^2]-\mu_X^2$$ but utterly failed to realize that one could also find $E[X^2]$ as the sum of $\operatorname{var}(X)$ and $\mu_X^2$.